# WARNING: Context manager doesn't exist

Tags: tomcat, cluster, session, sticky-sessions, warning

I have cluster setup with session replication. I have one load balancer with 2 tomcat instances as the worker nodes. In one of the node I am getting the WARNING. NOt sure what it really means. Session replication seems to be working fine just concerned about the message.

```
WARNING: Context manager doesn't exist:localhost#/myapp
```

Would appreciate any feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a related issue: http://www.coderanch.com/t/87863/Tomcat/Tomcat-Cluster-Woes

The workaround is to add: `org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener.level = SEVERE` to your `logging.properties` file.